# How to re-enable UEFI mode on Debian fresh install

Tags: debian, boot, uefi, bios

I replaced hard disk on laptop (2014 model) and made fresh install debian-11 in UEFI mode. Originally laptop come with Ubuntu factory-installed and Legacy BIOS (single OS). So I tried to make a clean UEFI mode installation on GPT partitioned drive, as the hardware seems are definitely UEFI-capable. So I installed Debian in clean UEFI mode, but I can't to get it boot. System don't detect Debian on hard drive. I installed latest BIOS update, tried different Boot menu settings, but this not help.

```
Boot Option #1 [debian (Drive not present)]
```

So I ended up with installing Legacy BIOS Grub, this allow me at least boot Debian. It boots in BIOS Legacy mode, but slow. I tried to set Boot mode to UEFI mode, Fast Boot: "Enabled" - it boos also, but almost the same slow. But this is not true UEFI mode, I think.

Also, the `efi` folder is missed in `'sys/firmware'` directory.

I installed ReEFInd, but don't tried yet to play with it. Is there way to re-enable UEFI mode?

Comment: `But this is not true UEFI mode, I think` what makes you think that since you've never booted debian in UEFI mode?

Comment: Are you using UEFI/gpt and have ESP for UEFI boot and bios_grub for BIOS boot? Then it is just a reinstall of the correct version of grub. Grub-pc for BIOS or grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Bravo When I tried `efibootmgr -v`, I got the message
`$ efibootmgr -v
EFI variables are not supported on this system.` In order to successfully use efibootmgr the EFI variables filesystem must be accessible. This requires that the system has been booted in EFI mode (and not through the firmware's MBR mode) as otherwise the EFI variables themselves cannot be accessed. From which I conclude that system booted in Legacy BIOS mode.

Comment: @oldfred boot-info [details](https://pastebin.com/raw/0bnS9FJJ).

Comment: You show both grub in MBR for BIOS and in the ESP for UEFI boot. You do have to boot in UEFI mode for efibootmgr -v to work. You also show mount of ESP in  fstab, so last fix or grub install must have been in UEFI mode. For BIOS to work with gpt, you must have a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. But try booting in UEFI mode and press escape after vendor screen & before grub  menu would normally appear. Do you then get grub menu? With single install, menu does not normally show. And then can you boot recovery mode or second line in grub or in sub-menu.

Comment: as I noted, in my boot menu already set _UEFI boot mode_, with' Load Legacy Option ROM' enabled. By press Esc I can get into Grub menu. `GNU GRUB version 2.02-20 *Debian GNU/Linux, Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux.` What I should to recover?

Comment: I don't know much about debian's kernel config, but you might try `modprobe efivars` and then `efibootmgr -v`.

Comment: It looks like your BIOS does not really allow setting the system to boot in UEFI-**only** mode. Instead, the "UEFI mode" seems to actually mean "prefer UEFI but fall back to legacy mode if UEFI fails". Since you don't have a `bios_grub` partition, the BIOS version of GRUB has been installed to read the `core.img` directly from the root partition - that is the most fragile way to install BIOS GRUB, and the GRUB documentation recommends against doing this. Any manipulations to the `core.img` file on the root partition might cause GRUB to start failing.

Comment: You said you cannot get the system to boot in UEFI mode. What exactly happened when you tried it? Did it get into GRUB? Did it load the kernel and then panic? Or did it proceed into initramfs and then crash into emergency shell mode? Each of these possible symptoms would suggest a different approach to fixing it.

Comment: no, there are no abnormal behavior, no crash or error messages when the system falls back to legacy mode if UEFI fails. I mean even if I set the "UEFI mode" in the bios boot menu, the system falls back into Legacy mode. The `efibootmgr -v` returns "EFI variables are not supported on this system", so EFI variables themselves cannot be accessed, meaning that system  dropped back into Legacy BIOS mode. `$ sudo modprobe efivars`
`modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.0-10-amd64`